# Determine the points in $[0, π]$ at which $f(x) = e^{2 \sin x−x}$ attains its maximum and minimum values.

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Determine the points in $[0, π]$ at which $f(x) = e^{2\sin(x)−x}$ attains its maximum and minimum values.

For this question I differentiated $f(x)$ and got $f'(x)= e^{ 2\sin (x)−x} (2\cos(x)-1).$

But I am not sure where to go from here. Usually for a simple equation you would factorise and get values for $x$ and then sub in these values into the original equation to find the max and min values. But I am not sure what I would do in this case.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please use MathJax for typesetting mathematical expressions in your question. It's easy to learn and makes things look much more organized and easy to read.

Comment: In order to get more than one character to a power (or inside a sqrt, etc.) use braces, { and }.  "e^{2 sin(x)- x}" inside dollar signs gives $e^{2sin(x)- x}$.  Similarly \sqrt{x^2 e^x] gives $\sqrt{x^2 e^x}$.

Comment: thank you for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you differentiate $f(x)$ and find $f'(x)=(2\cos(x)-1)e^{2\sin(x)-x}$, you should determine where $f'(x)$ is positive.

The inequality $(2\cos(x)-1)e^{2\sin(x)-x}> 0$ can be re-written as $2\cos(x)-1> 0$, since any exponential is positive. In $[0, \pi]$ one has $\cos(x)> \frac{1}{2}$ for $x\in[0, \frac{\pi}{3})$.

This means that $f$ is (strictly) increasing in $[0, \frac{\pi}{3}]$ and (strictly) decreasing in $[ \frac{\pi}{3}, \pi]$. We deduce that $f$ attains its maximum value at $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$, $f\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=e^{\sqrt{3}-\frac{\pi}{3}}$.

There are no stationary points other than $\frac{\pi}{3}$, which means the minimum of $f$ bust me attained either at $x=0$ or at $x=\pi$. Computing the values of $f$ at these points yields
$f(\pi)=e^{-\pi}<1=f(0),$
so the minimum of $f$ on $[0,\pi]$ is $f(\pi)=e^{-\pi}$.

Comment: could I ask that how did you get $\frac{}{3}$?

Comment: It is the only angle in the $[0, \pi]$ interval whose cosine is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: thank you! that was so much help

Answer (score 1):

So we want to find the maximum and minimum values of the function
$$f(x)=e^{2\sin(x)-x}.$$
A differentiable function $f$ has a maximum (or minimum) if $f'=0$.

Since $e^x$ and $2\sin(x)-x$ are differentiable, we know that their composition is differentiable and the derivative of such a composition is given by the chain rule and thus we find
$$f'(x)=e^{2\sin(x)-x}(2\cos(x)-1).$$
Above leads to the equation
$$e^{2\sin(x)-x}(2\cos(x)-1)=0.$$
This maybe looks scary or complicated, but remember that $e^x>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and thus you just have to solve
$$2\cos(x)-1=0.$$
I don't want to spoil everything and I think that you can try to catch up from here. Please ask if you need more help. Good luck!

Comment: "A differentiable function f has a maximum (or minimum) if and only if f′=0."  The "if"  part of this is wrong.   For example, if f(x)= x^3 then f'(x)= 3x^2 which is 0 at x= 0 but there is neither a maximum nor a minimum at x= 0.

Comment: Whoops, you're right! Should have thought about it for a second instead of writing it immediately.